# Nested quotes level 4 javascript error

Tags: php, javascript, nested, quotes

I have the following code (**I formated it to more lines, but in my source code I have it in one line**, because innerHTML doesn't like new lines somehow - but **that isn't the problem**...):

```
<?php
  echo "
    <img 
      src='1.png' 
      onclick='
        document.getElementById(\"my_div\").innerHTML=\"
          <img src=\\\"1.png\\\" onclick=\\\"alert(\\\\\\\"text\\\\\\\");\\\" />
        \";
      '
    />
  ";
?>
```

And somewhere in the body I have :

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

So, when I click on the image, i'll have the same image inside my_div. **The problem is, that when I click on the 2nd image, javascript doesn't alert anything**.

But when I change this:

```
alert(\\\\\\\"text\\\\\\\");
```

to this:

```
alert(MyText);
```

and add JavaScript variable MyText:

```
<script>
  MyText = "text";
</script>
```

it now works.

I think the problem is with those nested quotes:

```
\\\\\\\"
```

(level 4). Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT: please don't post here another methods of doing this, I'd like to know why those quotes doesn't work here..**

**SECOND EDIT: I need that php there, because this is only a piece of my code (in full code I need it to display images in cycle...)**

Comment: this code makes me want to *slash* my wrists... (eh, geddit... pun intended)

Comment: This is so awful. Please don't do this. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a quote character as data (instead of as an attribute delimiter) in HTML, you represent it as `&quot;` not `\"`

Comment: but in alert("something"); there aren't quotes represented as data, but as attribute (at least I think..), or not?

Comment: Those are quote characters inside an HTML attribute (`onclick`) value

Comment: Actually, they are quote characters inside an onclick attribute which is embedded inside another onclick attribute.

Comment: Frankly, you shouldn't use onclick, you should avoid innerHTML, and you should avoid sticking chunks of HTML in strings in PHP when you can just `?>...<?php`.

Comment: Ok, so everything that is between those `onclick="` and `"` is a data and all quotes that are between are written as `&quote`?

Comment: This is just a piece of code that I have, I need that `<?php  ?>` for cycle to draw the pictures..

Comment: It is data as far as the HTML parser is concerned. `"` characters need to be represented as `&quot;` not `&quote`. Remember you have **nested** values. `&` characters need to be represented as `&amp;`, so the nested attribute value will be `&amp;quot;`.

Comment: **Multiple levels of nested strings are a debugging and maintenance nightmare. Do not use them.**

Comment: And what if I want to use "3rd level" quotes as data? (first two levels are as - as you wrote - `&quot` and `amp`)

Comment: `&amp;amp;quot;`. Don't be sick.

Comment: so like this? `property="<img onclick=&amp;<img onclick="<img onclick=&quot;something&quot;>">&amp;>"`, or `property="<img onclick='<img onclick=&quot;<img onclick=&amp;something&amp>&quot;>'>"` sorry, little bit confusing :/

Comment: I have no idea what that code is trying to do. I repeat the earlier comment **Don't deep nest strings** and **Don't use onclick attributes**.

Comment: ok, I can use `&quot;`s and `&amp;`s, but, I think those quotes should work, (though they are not so nice solution)...

Comment: It is not a nice problem. (But if you think `\"` should work, then you are wrong as far as the values of HTML attributes are concerned)

Comment: Ok, thanks... I'll replace some of those \\\\\... with entities.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "dynamic" in your script - you're not inserting PHP variables, so why build that all from within a PHP echo? Simply have:

Or if you want to make it even cleaner:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addImg() {
        document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML='<img src="1.png" onclick="alert(\'text\')" />';
    }
</script>

<img src="1.png" onclick="addImg()" />
```

Comment: I wrote that to my second edit... if I didn't want to use php this would be good answer...

Answer (score 0):

refactor your JS into an external file (with a function that will do the onclick logic), and try outputting something simpler with php's echo

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div"></div>
<img src="1.png" class="my_img" />
<img src="2.png" class="my_img" />
<img src="3.png" class="my_img" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    $('.my_img').click(function() {
      $('#my_div').html($(this).clone().unbind());
      alert('text');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery for the most simplistic JS statements … @Marc B's solution is the much cleaner one.

Comment: If you want to spread inline javascript all over the place and want to mess with browser inconsistency and the stupidity of the DOM --- sure, just ignore frameworks